# How to make Popup truly modal (similar to MessageDialog)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to display a popup/modal dialog which includes a textbox or some other additional control.  To achieve this, I am setting a UserControl as a child of the Popup. The Popup's width and height are set to full screen so user interaction with ui elements in the background is not possible.

However, I realized that other popups can be displayed over the Popup that I was initially displaying. Thus making this not truly a modal control. Is there a way to make Popup completely modal (block any other UI elements including other Popups). Or is there another control i can use to display some kind of customized message dialog that is modal?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Other popups from other apps or from the OS? Or other popups from your program?

Comment: Other popups from my program

Answer (score 3):

You do it like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Popup x:Name="MyModalPopup" IsOpen="True" IsLightDismissEnabled="False">
        <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=OneWay}">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity=".25" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid Width="500" Height="400" Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Close">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=MyModalPopup}" PropertyName="IsOpen"/>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

The `IsLightDismissEnabled="False"` part is important.

Best of luck!

Comment: I set the IsLightDismissEnabled property to false however it doesnt stop from another popup being displayed by the application. Is this intended behavior? I know in MessageDialog, if you display a MessageDialog while one is being displayed already, an exception gets thrown

Comment: Ah. No. That is not part of the Popup design. To handle that, you could bind the IsOpen property to your ViewModel. Then test the value of that property before you attempt to show any other dialog. But no, a Popup does NOT prevent other Popups from being shown. There is no exact equiv to a ModelDialog in WPF.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT When resizing the window, the Grid isn't resizing with it. How can I get the Grid to resize? I thought it should be doing it since it's bound to to the LayoutRoot.